# What is the best way to identify updated items in an in memory list?

Tags: silverlight, syncfx

I'm using Siaqodb for my client side database engine in a Sync Framework silverlight project. I've switched to siaqodb because microsofts client side solution loads the entire database into memory at once and, as such, has a hard time handling large data.

I've bound a list of SiaqodbOfflineEntity objects to a silverlight datagrid in order to create an editable datagrid. Unlike microsofts solution, you can't bind the database entries directly to the datagrid. You have to query the database and bind a list of in memory objects to the datagrid. This causes a problem in that the database isn't immediatly updated when the datagrid cell is changed. I'm trying to find the best way to handle updates to the database after a change in the cell. I can't just update each item to the database because the siaqodb engine will mark the item as dirty even if no change was made to the object. This will cause conflicts when trying to sync. holding a cached version of the original list and then comparing each property of each object to find which ones have changed seems like it would work, but seems to be a bit cumbersome. I've also tried looking at some of the datagrids events but RowEditEnded doesn't appear to fire when a cell is edited and CurrentCellChanged seems to fire whenever I switch rows (odd).

There's got to be a better solution to this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "microsofts client side solution loads the entire database into memory at once" Pardon my skepticism, but I seriously doubt your claim is true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608 The sync fx uses change tracking, and you should only databind to a subset of your local DB on your client side anyway.

Comment: The problem is with silverlight and Microsoft's client side sync provider that uses Isolated Storage. Even when binding a subset of the database, the entire database is loaded into memory. More info can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synclab/thread/ad1ab1ac-0c4c-4856-88b6-81b8bae4d71b/

Answer (score 0):

So I've gotten this to work by changing my offline entity classes to implement iNotifyPropertyChange and I think this is a reasonable solution. I set the PropertyChanged event to a function that saves the object to the database. There is a VS package called [notifypropertyweaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) that will inject this code at compile time, reducing the amount of work needed to be done on auto-generated entity code.